# How to force an application to stop responding in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello how can i force my program to stop responding. I guess i should make a loop of something but i dont want to leak memory.

[image: this is what i want to do]

Could someone provide me an example?

Comment: what's the use case for functionality like this?

Comment: @Jonesopolis To test what happens in the system, when an App stops responding?

Comment: "force it to stop responding" is a weird way of saying it.  What you are looking at is the windows error reporting mechanism trying (slowly) to report the crash of the ffmpeg.exe application to Microsoft.  You can disable windows error reporting for that application with [WerAddExcludedApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/api/werapi/nf-werapi-weraddexcludedapplication?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and then it'll just crash and terminate instantly without showing that dialog.

Comment: Also **stopped responding** and **stopped working** are two different things.  As I mentioned, **stopped working** is how the WER mechanism reports that your application has terminated with a _crash_ (e.g. unhandled access violation exception). but **stopped responding** is how the window manager reports that you have created and shown a desktop window that has stopped pumping messages (message loop is not servicing windows messages and leaving messages in the queue without so much as peeking at them) (i.e. there's a window but GetMessage is not being called in a timely manner.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `Thread.Sleep(60_000)` on the UI thread. That will effectively hang your application for a minute.